# Get the max date from linq with mutiple joins and with multiple select fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have been scratching my head with this and cannot find a solution. I have a dataset like this,

```
JobID   DueDate     VisitID
4024082 2020-07-31  5267157
4024082 2020-07-29  5263915
4024082 2020-08-04  5269154
4024082 2020-07-23  5258774
4024082 2020-07-22  5255307
```

I want to get the result set like this,

```
JobID   Duedate     VisitID
4024082 2020-08-04  5269154
```

I have tried several ways but cannot get it to work. my linq query is

```
            var jobs = await (from j in _ctx.Jobs
                              join v in _ctx.Visits on j.JobID equals v.JobID
                              join p in _ctx.Products on j.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                              where j.IsProcessed== true
                              group v by new
                              {
                                  v.JobID,
                                  v.VisitID
                              }
                into g
                              select new
                              {
                                  JobId = g.Key,
                                  DueDate = g.Max(x => x.DueDate),
                                  VisitID = g.Key.VisitID
                              }).ToListAsync();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. I mean, I see only 1 table but I see a join in your sql query??? so more than 1 table?

Comment: Don't include the `DueDate` in te group by. It is weird, because you want the max date. I actually suspect you only want to group by the VisitId. The `JobID` is irrelevant, because you already have a `where` condition for that id.

Comment: @Iria edited and added another join. I didn't put all the joins avoid too much confusion.

Comment: @Silvermind removed the DueDate. Still it's returning 5 rows for me instead of 1

Comment: I don't get this piece: `&& j.JobID == 4024082` combined with the `ToListAsync()` at the end. That condition combined with the group looks like you need a `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. Maybe you added that `JobID` to test, but it isn't actually in the query and you are actually looking for the max duedate and accompanying visitID for **every** JobID.

Comment: @Silvermind apologies, yes you are right. it was only for testing purpose. i removed the JobID condtion. yes I'm looking for the max duedate and accompanying visitID for every JobID

Comment: if you don't want the joins you can do something like `_ctx.Jobs.Where(x => x.DueDate == _ctx.Jobs.Where(y => y.JobId == x.JobId).Max(y => y.DueDate))`

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty I do want the joins and the DueDate is in Visits. Not in Jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `Max` to get more than one value. You have to use a sorting mechanism here.

The following is an example of how to get the jobs grouped by the `JobID` and then every highest date with accompanying `VisitID`.

Here is the example. (I used LinqPad to test this):

```
void Main()
{
    var jobs = new[]
    {
        new Job { JobID = 4024082, DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-07-31", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), VisitID = 5267157 },
        new Job { JobID = 4024082, DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-07-29", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), VisitID = 5263915 },
        new Job { JobID = 4024082, DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-08-04", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), VisitID = 5269154 },
        new Job { JobID = 4024082, DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-07-23", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), VisitID = 5258774 },
        new Job { JobID = 4024082, DueDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2020-07-22", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), VisitID = 5255307 },
    };
    
    var query = from job in jobs
                group job by job.JobID into grp
                select grp.OrderByDescending(g => g.DueDate).FirstOrDefault();
    
    query.Dump();
}

public class Job
{
    public int JobID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public int VisitID { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
JobID    DueDate            VisitID
4024082  4-8-2020 00:00:00  5269154
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me :) I had to first insert the values from the database into the job class object and then queried the job class object using your query. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're using `VisitId` as part of the `GroupBy`. Since all the `VisitId` values are unique, you'll get a single record per group (and therefore one group for each record).

Perhaps you should only join on `JobId` if you want one group from those sample records. Then to get the `VisitID` for the row that had the most recent `DueDate`, we can order the group by `DueDate` (descending) and take the `VisitID` from the `First()` record:

```
var jobs = await (from j in _ctx.Jobs
                  join v in _ctx.Visits on j.JobID equals v.JobID
                  join p in _ctx.Products on j.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                  where j.IsProcessed== true
                  group v by v.JobID
                  into g
                      select new
                      {
                          JobId = g.Key,
                          DueDate = g.Max(x => x.DueDate),
                          VisitID = g.OrderByDecending(x => x.DueDate).First().VisitID
                      }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I get this error when I use OrderByDescending for the DueDate   .OrderByDescending(x => x.DueDate)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Comment: Can you try changing it to `VisitID = g.First(x => x.DueDate == g.Max(i => i.DueDate)).VisitID` and see if that works? Sorry I'm not where I can test this at the moment.

Comment: Now it gives this error  .Max(i => i.DueDate))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,